# Windows 10 Update Caused Loss Of Access To Microsoft Office

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I presume that the problem I am about to describe is actually very common and so this is a request
to please show me where the problem was originally solved on this site. Thank you in advance.

To put it at its simplest an upgrade to Windows made me lose access to my version of Office.

According to winver  I am now on Windows Version 2004 ( OS Build 19041.450 ).

What particularly annoys me is that I implemented that update manually ( rather than Microsoft dumping it on me ).
I have checked that Office is still in Program Files taking > 2.5G. And under Command Prompt it is still showing under Programs and Features.

But when I try to open a Word file, for instance, I get three separate windows each telling me it cannot find a particular dll file.

Comment: What version of Office? Which dll files are missing? The thing about waiting for MS to 'dump it on you' is that less-compatible machines get the updates after significant in the field testing on more compatible machines. Forcing an early update may have revealed an incompatibility MS was already aware of.

Comment: No issue here on any machine.  Try reinstalling Office.  Anything older than Office 2010 may not work.

Comment: You forced the 2004 upgrade although Microsoft has not yet verified it for your setup, so you are now a beta tester for Microsoft. My advice is to rollback to pre-2004 Windows and wait for it to be proposed by Windows Update.

Comment: @harrymc - If they installed the cumulative update they already were running 2004.  Please do not poorly advise the author.  If the author manually upgraded to 2004 that certainly isn’t clear by what they wrote

Comment: @FrankDesond - “ each telling me it cannot find a particular dll file” - What file?

Comment: @Ramhound: Quote: "I implemented that update manually ( rather than Microsoft dumping it on me )".

Comment: One could interpret that has the cumulative update or the feature update.  The author should clarify

Comment: @Ramhound: Which update needs to be verified with winver?

Comment: Could you please share us your Office version number, and the .dll files mentioned in error message? Thanks.

Comment: I tried again to open a Word file and had to type the names of the files in question. They were  in   :

 C:\ProgramFiles\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun 

namely  :

  VCRUNTIME140.dll
   MSVCP140.dll
   & ApiClient.dll

According to   Command Prompt,  I have  Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019.

I only answered those questions because it is the polite thing to do.

However somebody else has suggested a course of action that seems to be the way to go, 
namely “rollback to pre-2004 Windows”. 

Please tell me the relevant iso file to look for.